# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' for when i am trying to compress my csv file to zip

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, compression

I am trying to compress my csv file into a zip file before I e-mail it since the csv version is too big to be e-mailed currently.

However, i'm reaching an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' "

I currently have this code but i'm stumped for why this isn't working...

```
compression_options = {"method": "zip", "archive_name": f'report.csv'}

df.to_csv(f'../file location/report.csv.zip', compression=compression_options)
```

**EDIT:** **Adding in traceback and my pandas version information**

The pandas version I am using is 0.24.2. See below for full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a5743642b4c4> in <module>
      1 compression_options = {"method": "zip", "archive_name": f'report.csv'}
----> 2 df.to_csv(f'../file location/report.csv.zip', compression=compression_options)

/usr/local/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64/envs/jupyter-atp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3017                                  date_format=date_format,
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
-> 3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
   3020         formatter.save()
   3021 

/usr/local/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64/envs/jupyter-atp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in __init__(self, obj, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, cols, header, index, index_label, mode, nanRep, encoding, compression, quoting, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, quotechar, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
     56             encoding = 'ascii' if compat.PY2 else 'utf-8'
     57         self.encoding = encoding
---> 58         self.compression = _infer_compression(self.path_or_buf, compression)
     59 
     60         if quoting is None:

/usr/local/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64/envs/jupyter-atp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _infer_compression(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    303 
    304     # Compression has been specified. Check that it's valid
--> 305     if compression in _compression_to_extension:
    306         return compression
    307 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include full traceback you get

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Also, can you edit your question and put there full traceback?

Comment: Hi everyone. Added in my full traceback and included my version of pandas.

Comment: @bananas I suggest to upgrade the version of pandas. Version `0.24.2` if from Mar 12, 2019.

Comment: Not 100% sure how to upgrade pandas in Jupyter Notebook